# How to invert mouse y axis in Qube 2?

Tags: mouse, qube-2

I know it's not possible in the game options, and it won't be developped, but is there any workaround to this ?

So far I've tried a .NET Mouse inverter program, and Sakasa.exe

They DO invert y axis in Windows and Qube menus, but not in game.

Answer (score 1):

Oh ok I get it. It's not in "commands" menu or "video" like every other games, it's in a special menu called "FONCTIONS GENERALES" in french.

I was mislead by the menus and the only post about this saying it was not implemented :

https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/q-u-b-e-director-s-cut/271336-ps3-no-y-axis-inversion.html